# Integration of Laravel and JWT testing with postman application

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, jwt

JWT not work for me in Laravel 5 and I have three days in this but I don't know why almost nothing works.

> I am testing since postman application

**This if works fine:**

User registration method

```
public function store()
{
$credentials = $this->request->only('name','email', 'password');
$credentials['password'] = Hash::make($credentials['password']);

try {
  $user = User::create($credentials);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  return response()->json([
    'error' => 'User already exists.'
    ],HttpResponse::HTTP_CONFLICT
  );
}
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

**And this works fine too :**

login

```
public function store()
{

$credentials = $this->request->only('email', 'password');


  if( !$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {

    return response()->json([
        'Success' => false
        ], HttpResponse::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED
    );

  }

return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

**But** JWT Middleware, nothing restricts and allows the next request.

```
Route::get('/prueba-jwt-auth-restringido', [
'before' => 'jwt-auth',
function () {
  return 'Hola JWT :)';
}
]);
```

**And testing with postman**, sending the token, the next vardump always return false:

```
Route::get('/prueba-jwt-auth-restringido', [
'before' => 'jwt-auth',
function () {
  $token = JWTAuth::getToken();
  //$user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);    
  var_dump($token); // False 
}
]);
```

**Here the image in dropbox of screenshot** of postman request:
[screenshot postman request](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vli6gnw5t1y0fcb/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20-%20280515%20-%2015%3A03%3A43.png?dl=0)

For more information, my Kernel file is (part of middleware):

```
    protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
// 'gimnasio\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken', 
// 'gimnasio\Http\Middleware\Cors',
// 'Barryvdh\Cors\Middleware\HandleCors',
];
```

I omitted the CORS,  because I didn't allow me requests **(not working)** ,ever with:

```
  $response = $next($request);
  $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
  $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE');
  $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
  return $response;
```

> Excuse my English please, I appreciate your help. I've done everything with this problem.

Comment: In the POSTMAN request I changed token for Authorization but neither works.

Comment: Seems: .htaccess modification, but if i make upload it on a shared server. hopefully, i'll not have problems